# How to access fields of a query

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a query that from this code

```
cursor = db.MCAddrPortPairs.find({'Symbol' : symbol})[:1]
print str(json.dumps({'results': list(cursor)},
                        default = bson.json_util.default,
                        indent = 4))
```

returns the following doc:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "MCPort": 345, 
            "Symbol": "EUR/USD", 
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "56fc34e961fed32064e656b0"
            }, 
            "MCAddr": "239.0.0.222"
        }
    ]
}
```

MCAddr is a string and MCPort is an int. How do I access the fields MCAddr and MCPort in python?

**EDIT 1**

If I say

```
doc = db.MCAddrPortPairs.find({'Symbol' : symbol})[:1]

symbolMCIPAddrStr = doc["MCAddr"]
symbolMCPort = doc["MCPort"]
```

I get error:

```
File "mc.py", line 44, in initializeMongo
    symbolMCIPAddrStr = doc["MCAddr"]
  File "/home/idf/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 531, in __getitem__
    self.__check_okay_to_chain()
  File "/home/idf/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 342, in __check_okay_to_chain
    raise InvalidOperation("cannot set options after executing query")
pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: cannot set options after executing query
```

**EDIT 2**

If instead I say

```
doc = db.MCAddrPortPairs.find_one({'Symbol' : symbol})[:1]


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mc.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "mc.py", line 63, in main
    initializeMongo("EUR/USD") 
  File "mc.py", line 39, in initializeMongo
    doc = db.MCAddrPortPairs.find_one({'Symbol' : symbol})[:1]
TypeError: unhashable type
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python accessing data in JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241583/python-accessing-data-in-json-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the document returned by the cursor, no need to dump the results into JSON. I would also use [`find_one()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) if there is only one document needed:

```
doc = db.MCAddrPortPairs.find_one({'Symbol' : symbol})
port, address = doc["MCPort"], doc["MCAddr"]
print(port, address)
```

Comment: I don't want to print it. I want each value stored onto a local variable for example. And, there is only one item so there is nothing to loop.

Comment: @Ivan optimistically called it Edit 1 :). Please see the update. Thanks.

Comment: @Ivan oops, I need some sleep, fixed.